# Why there are duplicate rows after using group_by and mutate?

Tags: r

The sample data is as below:

| n | period | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1991 | 5 |
| 20 | 1991 | 5 |
| 16 | 1991 | 15 |
| 29 | 1991 | 15 |
| 77 | 1991 | 25 |
| 44 | 1991 | 25 |

I use the following code to get the sum from the data grouped by `period` and `age`:

```
#The name of dataset is a.
a %>% group_by(period,age)%>%
      mutate(n = sum(n))
```

But the result is:

| n | period | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | 1991 | 5 |
| 35 | 1991 | 5 |
| 45 | 1991 | 15 |
| 45 | 1991 | 15 |
| 121 | 1991 | 25 |
| 121 | 1991 | 25 |

Why there is duplicate rows? It is because it sums every element in each groups?

Comment: Use `summarise` instead of `mutate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `summarize()` function.  `mutate()` adds a column without consolidating the data.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
##Check if dplyr is installed, load if installed, install if not##
if(!require(dplyr)){
install.packages("dplyr")
}

##Creating the data##
n<-c(15,20,16,29,77,44)
period<-rep(1991, 6)
age<-c(5,5,15,15,25,25)

a<-data.frame(n=n, period=period, age=age)

##Calculation with summarize()##
a %>% group_by(period, age) %>% summarize(n= sum(n))
```